# Django, using select2 for choice field

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-select2

Now that select2 is shipped in django for the [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) feature, I have been looking for a way to use the select2 widget for a simple choice field which has many options. what's the current best way to do so?

Comment: Why the close vote?